# Add an external Javascript file depends of Component Name in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

Currently I'm creating an app using Angular2 and Typescript.

I have different components for different sections in the application (Home, Profile page, ...) and a JS file for each section (home.js, profile.js).

I'm wondering if it's possible to include this file depends of the component is being loaded.

Other thing I have tried is to add the javascript file into the view of the component but looks like Angular is stripping it out.

Any advice or a better way to do this would be really appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Why not just incorporate whatever is in the "home.js" and "profile.js" into their respective components? Why have them in a separate file?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it solved by myself.

What I've done is to implement AfterViewInit interface on my components, and load the script using jQuery.getScript method.

```
import {Component, AfterViewInit} from "@angular/core";
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: '../views/home.html',
    styleUrls: ['../../public/css/home.css']
})

export class HomeComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        jQuery.getScript('public/js/home.js');
    }
}
```

I hope this helps somebody with the same problem.